# Make hadoop split Lzo input files

Tags: hadoop, lzo

I'm using hadoop-lzo to process MR on large compressed data. Actually my jobs are automatically generated by a tool, but that's not the matter. My lzo compression works on all node (tried DistributedLzoIndexer), and i can also use streaming on splitted lzo files using this command line :

```
hadoop  jar /path/to/jar/hadoop-streaming-1.2.0.1.3.0.0-107.jar \
-input /path/to/testfile.lzo -output wc_test 
-inputformat com.hadoop.mapred.DeprecatedLzoTextInputFormat \
-mapper 'cat' -reducer 'wc -l'
```

It creates 11 map (according to my file size i guess) and process it normally.
But when I try any other jar file the lzo file is processed using only one map. So my question is

Normally hadoop would use Input Format according to compression codec ? My hadoop-lzo-0.4.3.jar is in the path, so i really do not understand why it still uses the default textformat.

**Is there any way of forcing hadoop to use LzoTextInputFormat ?**

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do this *other* jar let you specify the input format?  How are you calling it?

Comment: No, I can't specify ouput format. But for instance with the Wordcount example the lzo files should be split as they are with streaming ?

Comment: The wordcount example uses `TextInputFormat` by default I believe.  If you implement your own tools, you can set the input format.

Comment: I know that, but the thing is that I use lingual as request tool on my data. So it not possible to set the inputFormant for each job. I search for a trick that forces hadoop tu use LzoTextInputFormat and it's not a problem if no other format is then available. Do you have any clues ? :s

Comment: Progress : 
Actually I want cascading to use `LzoTextInputFormat`, it seems to be necessary to create a new scheme child class and I do not know how to proceed. Second point is that I want lingual to use it. If you know someone who is working on these subjects ? Thanks

Comment: I don't much about any of that... sorry